# how can i audit specific users' statements on specific tables in oracle

Tags: oracle, syntax-error, auditing

I want to do something like this:

```
AUDIT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON HR.EMP BY SCOTT BY ACCESS;
```

But it has wrong syntax. To fix it, i have to remove "BY SCOTT". How can i implement auditing similar like this in oracle?

In other words, Scott's statements on HR.EMP table should be audited, but not others.

Answer (score 0):

See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_4007.htm

You try to audit schema object. In this case you cannot specify auditing user (`BY SCOTT`). This is possible only when auditing sql statements.

Remove `BY SCOTT` clause:

```
AUDIT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON HR.EMP BY ACCESS;
```

Comment: Yes, you are right. My question was edited by someone :p. Actually the question was:
I want something similar like this: 
AUDIT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE ON HR.EMP BY SCOTT BY ACCESS;

In other words, I want to audit SCOTT on HR.EMP table, but not others.